# Unnest in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, grouping, unnest

I have this one data

```
USER_ID    EVENT_PARAMS
10001      walk
           sleep
           adventure
10002      movies
10003      book
```

how do I made in to this

```
USER_ID    EVENT_PARAMS            COUNT(EVENT_PARAMS)
10001      walk, sleep, adventure  3              
10002      movies                  1
10003      book                    1
```

I already tried using simple unnest but still not found what I looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_to_string](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_to_string) and [array_length](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_length):

```
select
  user_id,
  array_to_string(event_params, ', '),
  array_length(event_params)
from mytable
```